# perform permutation for picking combination of random files with out repetition

Tags: bash

What is the best way to pick random N files from various folders with out repetition?
I have tried shuf but I get repetition for file combinations some times.

```
#s can be any number between 1 to 6
for s in 1
do
        for ((setNumber=1; setNumber<=3; setNumber++))
        do 
            shuf -n${s} -e /data/testfile/*
        done
```

Output

```
/data/testfile/file3.txt
/data/testfile/file3.txt
/data/testfile/file2.txt
```

files in testfile folder

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt 
file6.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are running `shuf` 3 separate times?  Just run `shuf -n3 -e ...` once

Comment: @eduffy I have to place randomly picked sets in 3 separate files

Comment: You are picking one random file from that list three times, of course that can duplicate. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get combination of files 3 times with out repetition. s can be any number between 1 to 6

Comment: Do you mean "shuffle the files and pick any 's'"? Then `shuf -e * | head -n $s` -- otherwise, what does it mean to "get combination of files 6 times"?

Comment: I don't want to suffle files. lets say I have 4 files file1 file2 file3 file4. i will create combinations for any two files 3 times. the combinations might be (file1 file3) (file2 file4) (file3 file4)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `shuf` once, then grab ranges using bash's arrays:

```
files=( $(shuf -e *) )
s=1  # size of set
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do    
  b=$(($i*$s))
  echo ${files[@]:$b:$s} 
done
```